# How can I make a sample in r with the inclusion probabilities that I have saved in a vector?

Tags: r, sample

I have a data frame with 10 columns and 4 row and a vector of the length 10.

My vector contains 7x 0 and 3x 1. I want to make a sample of my data frame that picks exactly the 20 variables where in my vector a 1 appears.

E.g. if my vector goes like that: `0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0` then I want the 3rd, 5th and 6th row to be picked by the sample.

How can I do that?
Can I add anything to this command to make it work? `s <- sample_n(df$col1, 3)`

Comment: simply do `your_data[as.logical(your_vector), ]` or `your_data[your_Vector>0, ]`

Comment: @Axeman thanks. Though I think OP is not clear since they said `3rd, 5th and 6th` rows

Comment: the first code in the 1st comment worked already, thank you